# Scrolling on Magic Mouse isn't working on OS X 10.5.8 Leopard

Tags: mouse, scrolling, imac

I just bought a new Magic Mouse and the scrolling isn't working.

I've installed all of the software updates and the Wireless Mouse Software package but with no effect. Any ideas how I can get the scrolling working?

Answer (score 1):

Go into your mouse settings in preferences and make sure that scrolling is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled swiping and scrolling in System Preferences?